# Q: How to add automatic reply message to facebook messager Get Started message

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, slack, smooch

We integrated Facebook messanger - Smooch - Slack integration. Right now our reply rate on facebook go down because we dont have info that somebody click on Get Started button in messagenr. Is it possible to add/change facebook integration to add there auto reply after Get Started message for example: "Hello, write us your question?"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to accomplish a welcome message with Smooch and Messenger.

1. You can listen to the [`conversation:start`](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#conversation-events) webhook event to know when a user has clicked the Get Started button. Your application/bot could then use the [Post Message API](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#post-message) to send a message to the user
2. You can configure an [Auto-Reponse Whisper](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/automated-messages/), and/or [Out-Of-Office Message](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/office-hours/) to automatically send a reply when the user sends their first message (these responses will not trigger on the Get Started button, only when the user sends a message).
3. In your Facebook page's settings, you can configure an instant reply with the option "Send Instant Replies to anyone who messages your Page" under Settings > Messaging. Note that messages sent in this way will bypass Smooch entirely, and won't be present in the Smooch conversation history